# python getting plural of a noun

Tags: python, python-2.7

i am trying to make the same  functionality using `lambda` to get the plural of a word, this is my function (i want to write it in `lambda` form).

```
import re
def plural(noun):
    if re.search("[sxz]$",noun):
        return re.sub("$","es",noun)
    elif re.search("[^aeioudgkprt]h$",noun):
        return re.sub("$","es",noun)
    elif re.search("[^aeiou]y$",noun):
        return re.sub("y$","ies",noun)
    else:
        return noun+"s"
```

i want to make the same function job using `lambda` ,not sure where to start.
(i am using python 2.7)

Comment: lambda functions are supposed to be simple one-liners. This function is too complex  and not recommended to be turned into a lambda function

Comment: Your function ignores too many exceptions to be useful: for example, it fails for *sheep*, *money*, *man*. You might be able to squeeze that function into a single cryptic lambda expression, but the moment you need to extend it to cope with real examples, you will have to throw the lambda away.

Comment: @BoarGules there are a lot of english words that don't follow rules _woman_ _man_ ... ,i am not going to include all exceptions as you can see i only want to to write the same functionality using lambda (if possible)

Comment: @Amjasd Masdhash what is wrong with my solution where i use inflect library?

Comment: i am sure it works, i am just trying to work out the funcuntionality of `lamda` and how to use it (as stated in question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
rules=((lambda word:re.search('[sxz]$',word),lambda word:re.sub('$','es',word)),
    (lambda word: re.search('[^aeioudgkprt]h$', word),lambda word: re.sub('$', 'es', word)),
    (lambda word: re.search('[^aeiou]y$', word),lambda word: re.sub('y$', 'ies', word)),
    (lambda word: re.search('$', word),lambda word: re.sub('$', 's', word)))
def plural(noun):
    for findpattern,rule in rules:
        if findpattern(noun):
            return rule(noun)

print plural('boy')
```

This your functions as lambda rules, it will search for pattern if it's true,apply rule

Answer (score 2):

```
import inflect

result = inflect.engine().plural('bike')
```